# Page display different wallpaper depending on which of two sites linked from

Tags: php, background

I have two pages, both of which include a php includes link to a third page.

At the moment I have two versions of this third page, both with different background to suit where on the page they need to be. Rather than maintaining two mostly identical pages, is there anyway of having one, BUT can tell which of the two links called it, and subsequently display different background.

I know a solution would be based on the original two pages, but for complicated reasons, it really has to be based on the third php file.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From the calling pages, define a variable:

```
$from = 1;
include('third.php');
```

or

```
$from = 2;
include('third.php');
```

In `third.php`, test that variable:

```
if ($from == 1)
  // do something
else
  // do something else
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Could you just glance over the way I've wrapper my code:                                      <?PHP $from = 1; include "information_request_form.php" ; ?> and <?PHP if ($from == 1)
  <img src="images/2.png"/>;
else
  <img src="images/1.png"/>;
?>

Comment: @user2406993 you'll have to exit/enter from PHP and/or use echo to output your html, but yeah, that's the idea

Comment: Sorry I'm a real newby - could you explain with this line <?PHP if ($from == 1) <img src="images/2.png"/>; else <img src="images/1.png"/>; ?>

Comment: `<?php if ($from == 1) echo '<img src="images/2.png"/>'; else echo '<img src="images/1.png"/>'; ?>`

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a templating engine.

A templating engine allows you to decouple the application logic from the presentation of your website. Therefore, you'll have your third page to decide which template it has to render based on your logic and the template engine will build the HTML page with the desired background.

I personally suggest you to take a look at [Smarty template engine](http://www.smarty.net). Its syntax is almost identical to PHP so the learning curve is really smooth.

Here's a pseudocode example with PHP and Smarty

```
//do something

$pageType = getPageType($args);

//do something more

$smarty = new Smarty();
//if needed, configure smarty here

$smarty->assign('background', $pageType);
//other assignments...

//render the third page template
$smarty->display('third_page.tpl');
```

And here's the pseudocode for `third_page.tpl`

```
<html>
...
<style>
    <!-- load background {$background} -->
</style>
<body>
    <!-- third page content -->
</body>
</html>
```